# Shadow-root sibling elements disappear on attachShadow() call

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, shadow-dom

When I call `host.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})` on a div containing a few elements inside, the contents of the div seemingly disappears. The elements are still visible from devtools but are no longer visible on screen.

It doesn't matter if i fill the shadowRoot with anything; as soon as the shadow is attached the div's children disappear.

Demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrBdOe

Why does the content disappear? I've seen it on websites so I know it's possible somehow. See the code for https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/quick-tour for example, the `<pw-shell>` node has a shadow-root and several siblings co-existing. What's going on there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Shadow DOM content will replace the original DOM subtree of the host where it (the shadow root) is attached. That's the expected behaviour of a Shadow DOM (hence this name).

You can make it appear by using the  element in the Shadow DOM.

```js
host.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    .innerHTML = 'Original DOM: <slot></slot>, in the Shadow DOM'
```

```html
<div id=host>
Lite DOM
</div>
```

You should read the [tutorial about Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom) for further details.

Comment: Yes. Using qwerty's original CodePen, add `<slot></slot> to the end of the innerHTML string: https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/WXKKwy

Comment: Slots are the answer!

Comment: Quick TLDR for this topic: https://dev.to/activenode/web-components-shadow-dom-shadow-css-tldr-4cgh