# Appending a button to an existing shadowroot element is not correct

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

```js
var shadow = document.getElementById(
        "3rd-party-div"
      ).shadowRoot; 
      
let style = document.createElement("style");
      style.textContent = `
      .custom_button{
    
    padding: 10px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
`
shadow.appendChild(style);
let customButton = document.createElement("button");
customButton.setAttribute("class", "custom_button");
customButton.innerHTML = "Back to Overview";
```

I have a shadowRoot in my HTML page which I am accessing via this piece of code

```
var shadow = document.getElementById(
        "3rd-party-div"
      ).shadowRoot;
```

Now I want to create a button and attach it to this shadowroot. Below code -

```
      let customButton = document.createElement("button");
      customButton.setAttribute("class", "custom_button");
      customButton.innerHTML = "Back to Overview";
```

And I append this button to shadow element with this code `shadow.appendChild(customButton);`
I have my css styling which I also append to the shadowroot.

Now my button is coming in the page, but it below my shadowroot div. Is there anyway to keep it as part of my shadow div itself?

Comment: `shadow.appendChild` would append it to the shadow root. Do you want to append it to the shadow host (the "3rd-party-div" element) instead, making it a sibling of the shadow root?

Comment: Click the [< >] icon in the editor and try to include a working Snippet in your question. You are now mentioning a lot of  ingredients we don't see code of.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman added snippet.

Comment: @MiKo now it makes sense. My 3rd-party-div element has an another div inside it and what I would like to do is to attach it to that div. In my code, I had it appended to shadow root directly and that;s why it did not come properly. Is there a way to append my button to the div inside of my shadowroot?

Comment: @user1734698 I posted an answer, is that what you want?

Comment: Click the blue Run button... your code snippet is incomplete, produces an error

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you want to achieve, but based on your recent comment I think you want to keep the content of your div, attach a shadow DOM to it and add a button to the same div.

Attaching a shadow [will replace the original DOM subtree of the host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501350/186787). If you want to preserve it, you can use a `<slot>`.

```js
const thirdPartyDiv = document.getElementById("3rd-party-div");

// Button inside the 3rd-party-div
const customButtonExt = document.createElement("button");
customButtonExt.innerHTML = "Back to Overview (inside 3rd party div)";
thirdPartyDiv.appendChild(customButtonExt);

// Attach shadow and keep the content of the div by using a <slot>
thirdPartyDiv.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = '<slot></slot>';
      
const shadow = thirdPartyDiv.shadowRoot; 
      
const style = document.createElement("style");
style.textContent = `
  .custom_button {
    padding: 10px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
`;
shadow.appendChild(style);

// Button inside the shadow
const customButton = document.createElement("button");
customButton.setAttribute("class", "custom_button");
customButton.innerHTML = "Back to Overview (inside shadow)";

shadow.appendChild(customButton);
```

```html
<div id="3rd-party-div">
  <div>Content of the 3rd-party div!</div>
</div>
```